# Tiles 3 override a nested attribute

Tags: struts2, tiles, apache-tiles

I'm have a problem with Tiles 3 with Struts2.  I can't seem to override an attribute of a nested tiles-definition.

Here's the relevant parts of my web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Here's my struts.xml

```
    <package name="helloworld" extends="tiles-default" namespace="/secure">
    <result-types>
        <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" default="true" />
    </result-types>

    <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="s2sLogging"  class="com.s2s.web.s2.S2Interceptor" />
        <interceptor-stack name="s2sStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="timer" />
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
            <interceptor-ref name="s2sLogging" />
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>
    <default-interceptor-ref name="s2sStack" />

    <action name="howitworks"    class="com.s2s.web.s2.S2RootAction" >
        <result name="success" type="tiles">.howItWorks.landing</result>
    </action>
```

Here's my tiles.xml

```
<definition name="s2s.rightNav"                         template="/WEB-INF/s2/pages/common/rightNav.jsp"  >
</definition>
<definition name="s2s.pageContent"                      template="/WEB-INF/s2/pages/pageContent.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="box"                           value="true" />     <!-- change to false to remove grey box behind text  -->
    <put-attribute name="rightNav"                      value="s2s.rightNav" />
</definition>

<!-- overall page layout -->
<definition name="page.layout"                      template="/WEB-INF/s2/pages/page.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="pageTitlePrefix"               value="s2s.com"         type="string"/>
    <put-attribute name="pageTitle"                     value=" "                       type="string"/>
    <put-attribute name="headContent"                   value="s2s.headContent" />
    <put-attribute name="extraHeadContent"              value=".tile.empty" />
    <put-attribute name="topNav"                        value="s2s.topNav" />
    <put-attribute name="topNavSubNav"                  value="s2s.topNavSubNav" />
    <put-attribute name="pageContent"                   value="s2s.pageContent" />              
    <put-attribute name="footer"                        value="s2s.footer"              type="string"/>
    <put-attribute name="SEOkeywords"                   value="s2s, ship to storage, moving storage services, self-storage, moving storage, self storage shipping, send to storage, ship to self storage, shipping storage, mail storage, self storage pick up and delivery" />
    <put-attribute name="SEOdescription"                value="The worlds most convenient self-storage. s2s combines shipping, elf storage, and service -- prices from $2.79 a box. Boxes are picked up from your doorstep and stored at our climate controlled, secure warehouse. s2s's flexible pricing grows as your needs grow. A valuable shipping and storage resource for moving, relocation, offices, students, trade shows, and more." />
    <put-attribute name="pageSEOkeywords"               value=" "                       type="string"/>
    <put-attribute name="pageSEOdescription"            value="s2s.com - "  type="string"/>
    <put-attribute name="debugPage"                     value="v.101" type="string"/>
</definition>

<!-- PAGE DEFNINITIONS -->

<definition name=".howItWorks.landing"              extends="page.layout">
    <put-attribute name="pageTitle"                 value="How Mail Storage Works "         type="string"/>
    <put-attribute name="selectedTab"               value="howItWorks"                      type="string"/>
    <put-attribute name="pageSEOkeywords"           value="how it works, "                  type="string"/>
    <put-attribute name="pageSEOdescription"        value="How It Works | "                 type="string"/>
    <put-attribute name="rightNavCTAs"              value="estimateBoxSize,helpfulLinks"    type="string"   cascade="true"/>
    <put-attribute name="mainBodyContent"           value="s2s.howItWorks.MainBodyContent"                  cascade="true"/>
</definition>
<definition name="s2s.howItWorks.MainBodyContent" template="/WEB-INF/s2/pages/howItWorks.jsp" />
```

I want to override the **mainBodyContent** and the **rightNavCTAs** attributes of  with the definition of **.howItWorks.landing**.  However, when I print out the actual value in the jsp , rightNavCTAs is null (and I think it means that the value is not propagating down even though I use cascade="true").

According to the Apache Tiles 3 documentation [here](https://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/advanced/nesting-extending.html), I should be able to nest using subdefinitions like I have above, and then extend and override attributes. The cascade is supposed to propagate attributes.

Needless to say, I can't get it to work.  Can anyone spot my flaw?

---

as Requested, here are my jsps.  thanks for looking.

all jsps have this at the top:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
```

Here is My page.jsp (stripped of css):

```
<tiles:importAttribute scope="request"/>
<html>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/stylesheet.css"  />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/jmesa.css">
        <title>
            <tiles:getAsString name="pageTitlePrefix" /> - <tiles:getAsString name="pageTitle" />
        </title>
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="headContent" />
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="extraHeadContent" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page"> 
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="topNav" />
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="topNavSubNav" />
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="pageContent" />
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is may *pageContent.jsp* (stripped of css):

```
    <table >
    <tr>
        <td >
            <!-- Box Table Starts here-->
            <s:if test="%{#attr['box'] == 'true'}">
                <table >
                    <tr>
                        <td  /></td>
                        <td /></td>
                        <td  /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td >&nbsp;</td>
                        <td >
                            <!-- Insert Main Body Content1 -->
                            <tiles:insertAttribute name="mainBodyContent"  />
                            <!-- End of Main Body Content1 -->
                        </td>
                        <td >&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td  /></td>
                        <td >&nbsp;</td>
                        <td /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </s:if>
            <s:else>
                <!-- Insert Main Body Content -->
                <tiles:insertAttribute name="mainBodyContent" />
                <!-- End of Main Body Content -->
            </s:else>
        </td>
        <td >&nbsp;</td>
        <td >
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="rightNav" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- End Page Content -->
```

And here is my *howitworks.jsp* (again, stripped of css).  This is supposed to override the **mainBodyContent** attribute, but I can't get it to work :

```
<table >
        <tr>
            <td  />Test... how it works</td>
            <td /></td>
            <td  /></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Not clear in what page that doesn't work. Can you add your jsp-s.

Comment: @AleksandrM added my jsps. Thanks for looking.

Comment: There is no `rightNavCTAs` in your pages. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: @AleksandrM  The `rightNavCTAs` and `mainBodyContent` in the  `howItWorks.landing` definition do not override the `page.layout` .  (sorry for delayed responses... I'm traveling on assignment a fair amt, with laptop ban when traveling).  Also, the `rightNavCTAs` attribute is in the `righNav.jsp` -- I'll post this once I can get access.